# Saving nested models in Django-NoRel gives "can't encode" error

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, django-nonrel

I can save a "Node", "Link" but not a "Graph" (see error below).
Using pymongo 2.1.1, Django-NoRel, Python 2.7:

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import SetField, ListField, EmbeddedModelField

class Graph(models.Model):
    links = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Link'))

class Link(models.Model):
    parent = EmbeddedModelField('Node')
    child = EmbeddedModelField('Node')

class Node(models.Model):
    extent = SetField() # set of strings e.g. "Gene-Bmp4"
    intent = SetField() # set of strings
```

--

```
n1 = Node(extent=set(["Gene-bmp4"]),intent=set(["Attr1", "Attr2"]))
n2 = Node(extent=set(["Gene-fp4"]),intent=set(["Attr3", "Attr4"]))
link = Link(parent=n1, child=n2)
links = [link]
g = Graph(links=links)
g.save()
```

produces the error:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pymongo/collection.py:312: RuntimeWarning: couldn't encode - reloading python modules and trying again. if you see this without getting an InvalidDocument exception please see api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#does-pymongo-work-with-mod-wsgi

```
Exception Type:     InvalidDocument
Exception Value:    Cannot encode object: set(['Attr2', 'Attr1'])
Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/pymongo/collection.py in insert, line 312
```

Does anyone has any idea what should I do??

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug to me. Please open a ticket at https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you cannot encode an object of type 'set' as BSON since BSON has not 'set' type.

The best solution is to covert the set to an array before you go to save the graph.